# Unable to Mount External Harddrive

Tags: mount, hard-drive, exfat

Hey guys when ever I try to mount my external hard drive this error pops up

```
Unable to access “HD710”

Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/roshan/HD710: 
Command-line `mount -t "exfat" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,namecase=0,errors=remount-ro,umask=0077" "/dev/sdb1" "/media/roshan/HD710"' 
exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: unknown filesystem type 'exfat'
```

EDIT: The name of my harddrive is HD710.

Answer (score 0):

You could see what types of "filesystems" your system supports via:

```
cat /proc/filesystems
```

and read about them with:

```
man filesystems
```

and, respond to the `...mount: unknown filesystem type 'exfat'` by changing `exfat` to `vfat`.